# How can I get a container div to expand to height of its contents?

Tags: css, html, height

I want the container div to expand to the height of the div's inner contents (the unordered list). I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul id="list">
        <li>stuff</li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS: (doesn't work)

```
.container {
    width: 332px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0.4em; 
    position: relative; 
    overflow-y:scroll; 
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

#list {
    position: absolute;
    height:auto;
    width:317px;
}
```

Comment: Why is list absolutely positioned ? This wont work like you want it to because absolutely positioning the child will take it out of the normal flow.

Comment: I agree with @Interstellar_Coder - can you please tell us what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove `height: 100%;` and `position: relative;` from `.container` and remove `position: absolute;` from `#list` .

Comment: ...unless there's some reason for those to be there which you're not telling us, or accidentally stripped out of your example.

Answer (score 4):

The `overflow-y:scroll` conflicts with your requirement that you want it to expand, as does the `height:100%` since 100% is based on the `.container`'s containing element height.

What you need to do is remove `height:100%` and `overflow-y:scroll`, replace with `overflow-y:hidden` and I **believe** it should work.

PS. Why do you need to the `#list` to be `position:absolute`?

Answer (score 0):

Two options: 
Either add height:100% for #list

```
#list{
position: absolute;
height:auto;
width:317px;
height: 100%;
}
```

Or make container as ID:

```
#container{
... 
}
```

Comment: hm, this one, where you combine both of my methods, work: http://jsfiddle.net/2weVn/

Comment: IgnasK there's many things wrong with that fiddle, one of which is that container is a class not an id.

Comment: To see what he's talking about, here's the same fiddle with background colors http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/2weVn/1/

Comment: eh, I copied the old fiddle, that's why.

Here's the working one: http://jsfiddle.net/2weVn/2/

Answer (score 0):

Set a min-width and/or max-width attribute for .container